# Ghost MACs roaming my network

Tags: networking, dhcp, local-area-network, dhcp-server, dnsmasq

I'm using a router with dnsmasq providing dhcp services. From some time my laptop is not getting assigned IP. The router complains:

```
May 13 08:16:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[432]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.234 86:16:f9:4b:65:27 
May 13 08:16:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[432]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.234 86:16:f9:4b:65:27 monster
May 13 08:16:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[432]: not giving name monster.lan to the DHCP lease of 192.168.1.234 because the name exists in /etc/hosts.dnsmasq with address 192.168.1.100
May 13 08:16:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[432]: not giving name monster to the DHCP lease of 192.168.1.234 because the name exists in /etc/hosts.dnsmasq with address 192.168.1.100
```

Now the strange thing is none of laptop's interfaces has 86:16:f9:4b:65:27 MAC! Moreover if you paste this MAC to any MAC finder, it will tell you there's no such vendor!

Doing arp -a will of course display this MAC among others in my network, on one occasion I've seen another 86:16... MAC.

What could that possibly mean?

Answer (score 1):

dnsmasq is a broken POS. You don't need to effectively route your network traffic through a locally hosted dhcp server on your computer. Disable dnsmasq by commenting it out (adding a # before) the line dns=dnsmasq in 
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Then restart the network manager with
sudo service network-manager restart

And cat /etc/resolv.conf should actually list the dns servers you are using.

Comment: I don't have dnsmasq on my computer, I have it on my router. It provides DHCP services for my network.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Not sure, then.